# Infill line distance at 100% infill density

Tags: infill

[image]

I want to understand what the infill line distance of 0.4mm signifies. I am printing at 100% infill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your nozzle width (and thereby your default line width) is 0.4 mm. The infill line distance of 0.4 mm means that the centers of lines are spaced 0.4 mm apart from each other, so that they exactly touch their neighbors at their width (0.2 mm from the center in either direction).